# How to deal with missing rows in my stored procedure loop?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure which loops through `article` values, fetch `tag1` and insert it into `article_tag` table:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dt1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE maxid INT;
    DECLARE x INT;
    DECLARE t VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE ntag1 int;
    SET maxid = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `article`);
    SET x = (SELECT MIN(id) FROM  `article`) ;
    WHILE x<= maxid DO 
        SET t = (SELECT tag1 from `article` WHERE id=x);   
        SET ntag1 = (SELECT count(*) from `article_tag` WHERE tag=t);

        IF ntag1 = 0 
        THEN 
            INSERT INTO `article_tag` (tag, slug, frequency) VALUES (t, t, 1);
        ELSE 
            UPDATE  `article_tag` SET frequency = frequency + 1 WHERE tag=t;
        END IF;
        SET  x = x + 1; 
    END WHILE;
END$$
```

This [works fine](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ymPtabSksRUMSBep7SyX8/15) when there are rows with `id` in the while loop, but when when there are some missing `id`s in between (like [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ymPtabSksRUMSBep7SyX8/17))
I get

```
Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'tag' cannot be null
```

I'm wondering what is the idiomatic way to deal with such missing rows?

Comment: Add a condition and skip it?

Comment: @tadman what condition?

Comment: Something like `t IS NULL`.

Comment: Yes, this works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3ymPtabSksRUMSBep7SyX8/21 . But wondering it's the best way?

Comment: As you really haven't explained why you have this in the first place it's hard to say. Normally stored procedures with this degree of complexity are a sign the database isn't properly relational. Why can't this be done as an `INSERT INTO article_tags SELECT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` instead?

Comment: It looks like you're really just trying to do an insert/update on collision which is precisely what [`ON DUPLICATE KEY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) is all about. This requires a `UNIQUE` constraint, but those are easy to add.

Comment: @tadman this is an effor to extract data from a fragmented/legacy database. The problem here is missing rows, not duplicate ones.

Comment: I'm just observing that this could probably be a single query, regardless of the situation. `INSERT INTO article_tag (tag, slug, frequency) SELECT tag1,tag1,1 FROM article WHERE tag1 IS NOT NULL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE frequency=frequency+1` or something.

Comment: This is great. The catch22 however is that in my original legacy database `tag1` and `slug` are not the same, so I could not find any better way that appealing to the clunky procedure.

Comment: You're inserting the same `t` value here twice. I'm just proposing doing the same in a single query.

Comment: Not sure, why not use cursor instead of the manual iterations? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Comment: if SELECT tag1 from `article` WHERE id=x finds nothing then t will be set to null so just put an if test in after this statement.

Comment: @tadman I tried your query, but since `tag1` and `slug` of my original `article` table are different pairs on each row, `ON DUPLICATE KEY` never reached and results in a `article_tag` table with as many rows as the `article`, which is obviously not intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use loop with cursor, so you will only loop through existing records and do not need to check for NULL.
Something like this:

```
DELIMITER \\
CREATE PROCEDURE dt1()
BEGIN
    DECLARE t VARCHAR(30);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT tag FROM `article` ORDER BY id;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    loop1: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO t;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;

        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @cnt from `article_tag` WHERE tag = t;

        IF @cnt = 0  THEN 
            INSERT INTO `article_tag` (tag, slug, frequency) VALUES (t, t, 1);
        ELSE 
            UPDATE `article_tag` SET frequency = frequency + 1 WHERE tag = t;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
END
\\
DELIMITER ;
```

See manual for details:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cursors.html

Sure, if possible I'd use INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE as already mentioned.

Comment: Very interesting. As a beginner to SP, I did not encounter loop/cursors before. Thanks!